# READ/RECEIVE sms without SEND permission

Tags: android, permissions

I ask for a simple READ_SMS (or RECIEVE_SMS) permission - but the user get a popup asking if he gives permission to SEND SMS.

is there a way i can avoid that? 
I'm not planning on sending sms on behalf of the users, and think this will just make them click on 'no'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As official doc says permissions are grouped together and for each group the prompt dialog's content is same.
You could see [this ref](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#perm-groups).

If user rejected, you could tell them why you should need this permission and **only read sms**. Here is [a ref](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-request)

I think if your app is useful and explain the reason for read sms clearly.
User would accept it undoubtedly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My app does explain well why do I need READ permissions. But then it's followed by a popup to SEND - which raises a warning flag to the user. I would like to avoid it. 

So you're saying this CAN be done only after he rejects? I'll check this out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way i can avoid that?

Do not ask for any SMS-related permissions. The dialog that the user sees is by permission group, and in the case of SMS, the permission group includes permissions for sending and receiving SMS.

Note that you cannot read SMS unless you are the user's chosen SMS client, if you will be [distributing your app via the Play Store](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/). You are welcome to request a waiver for this policy, and you are welcome to distribute your app in other ways.

Comment: I see. thanks for the reply. Too bad, I will have to get permissions I'm not intending to use which will drive users away :/